# Oracle SQL foreign key from the same table

Tags: oracle

How can I set a foreign key constraint if the attribute to be set to foreign key is from the current table instead of another table.

When I try setting constraint in the normal way with

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT a_fk FOREIGN KEY (att)
    REFERENCES a (att);
```

, the error report "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list" is given.

Comment: `att` still needs to be a primary or unique key, as the message says, even if it is also a foreign key. This looks odd though - do you really want that column to refer to itself? Won't that always be true?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT a__att__u UNIQUE (att);` fixes the problem ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ySg4Dj9g)). However, as @AlexPoole states, it does not really make sense as you are looking to see if all the non-`NULL` values in the `att` column are contained all the non-`NULL` values in the `att` column (which will always be true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as Alex commented, what would be the purpose of referencing the same column? Usual case is `employees` table that looks like this:

```
SQL> create table employees
  2  (emp_id       number  constraint pk_employees primary key,
  3   ename        varchar2(20),
  4   mgr_id       number
  5  );

Table created.
```

- `emp_id` (employee's ID) is a primary key column
- `mgr_id` (employee's manager) is supposed to be a foreign key column that references `emp_id`

  - meaning: manager has to be one of the employees

Therefore, you'd set it as

```
SQL> alter table employees add constraint fk_emp_mgr
  2    foreign key (mgr_id)
  3    references employees (emp_id);

Table altered.
```

As Oracle told you, you have to reference unique or primary key column (which `emp_id` already is).

That's what you, basically, asked for:

> How can I set a foreign key constraint if the attribute to be set to foreign key is from the current table instead of another table.

---

Finally, can you really do what you tried, i.e. to set foreign key that references the same column? Yes, you can (as long as it already is a primary or unique key);

```
SQL> create table employees
  2  (emp_id    number constraint pk_employees primary key);

Table created.

SQL> alter table employees add constraint fk_emp_mgr
  2    foreign key (emp_id)
  3    references employees (emp_id);

Table altered.
```